# question in designing a class in java

Tags: java, interface, enums

I have a Employee class and department class.Now within employee i have a department as its member.The department can be either of 2 type "HR" or "Admin".Now should i declare departmentype as a enum in a separate interface and then should model department class as show below?

```
public interface Myconstants{

  enum Depttype{HR,Admin};

}

public class Department{

 Myconstants.Depttype depttype;
 Department(Myconstants.Depttype depttype){
   this.deptype = deptype;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would simply declare the enum on the Department class.

```
public class Department {

  public enum Depttype{HR,Admin};

  private Depttype depttype;

  Department(Depttype depttype) {
   this.deptype = deptype;
  }
}
```

Comment: which practice would be better? to declare constants in seperate interface like i have done, or like u have done?

Comment: @Maurice :Am confused.Which s better,Myne or eljensos?

Comment: `Depttype` is the type of a department, so it is naturally tied to `Department`. No need to create a separate "global" constants-declaring  type.

Comment: thanks all.Can you please help me on the new commnet posted by me for Nicolas answer

Comment: Don't ask questions in the comments like that. You already know where the "Ask Question" button is.

Answer (score 0):

As written, why not just declare an enum?

You're declaring an enum and then wrapping it in a class, for no clear benefit.

Comment: thanks.Can you please help me on the new commnet posted by me for Nicolas answer

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why the enum should be part of an interface. If the "Department type" as you intend it is supposed to be a caracterization of your "Departments", then the proper way seems to declare the enum as attribute of the `Department` class.

Comment: ok, thanks.Now i have one more doubt.I want to create one instance of HR and one instance of Admin department when my application loads(console app) and use those instances throughout my program.How can i use same instances everywhere in different classes?.For example i read a employee from  csv file and then create a employee object.Now to create a employee object i must use the department object.I have to set proper value of department depending on the value of department read from file.How to do it?

Comment: You seem new to Java. You should read tutorials first here : http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html, but basically, to do that, you :

1) read your document, create class `Employee e; Department d;` 
2) create for each employee  `e = new Employee();`
and `d = new Department(<type>);`
3) bind the department to employee :
`e.setDepartment(d);`

or, depending how you made the constructors :

`e = new Employee(new Department(HR));`

Answer (score 0):

We declare enums separately, as straightforward enums in their own constants directory.  Departmenttype could in the future be used elsewhere in the app ?  And keeping all the constants/enums in the same place makes it easy for the developers.